# Should I create an Index for a large insert operation in mysql?

Tags: mysql

Lets say i have the following table with 8 billion columns:
    Subject text, Predicate text, Object text
And now i want to create another table to count the different text values like this:

```
CREATE TABLE Nodes (id BIGINT UNSIGNED PRIMARY KEY AUTO INCREMENT, val TEXT,     count BIGINT UNSIGNED);
INSERT INTO Nodes(val,count)
SELECT Subject, COUNT(*) as count FROM Triples GROUP BY Subject
```

Would an index over Subject Predicate and Object increase or decrease the speed of the insertion?

Answer (score 2):

A very general rule of thumb: indices typically *decrease* write speeds, while *increasing* read speeds.

Answer (score 0):

It would decrease the speed, as with each insert the table would be re-indexed and the number of rows to index is increasing...  Normally if I have a large set of records to insert, I'll drop all indexes prior to the insert run and then recreate them at the end...

Answer (score 0):

But there is no Index to be written.
To clarify: Im thinking anout adding an index like this:
`ALTER TABLE Triples ADD INDEX (Subject(767)), ADD INDEX (Predicate(767)), ADD INDEX (Object(767))`
So that the read operations for the INSERT statements go faster (GROUP BY and so on).

The question is, if it's worth it to compute the indices rather than allow a fulltext match in the INSERT operations.